# tmux with bash prompt to compile c code

Tags: vim, screen, tmux

I don't know whether something like this possible with tmux (If I'm not wrong, Its not possible with screen command). I would like to have two vertical windows. one to have vim opened c code and second to compile that code.

```
    Terminal
     -----------------------
             |  
             |
      c-code |  bash#gcc code.c
             |  run others etc
             |
     -----------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Ctrl+b %** to  split a window vertically.
Then open vim in the left window.

Ref:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Key_bindings

Answer (score 1):

It may be too obvious but… you can also open another terminal emulator window.

Or simply use `<C-z>` to suspend Vim.

Or compile from Vim itself and see the output, if any, in the quickfix window.

Comment: I use the <C-z> and get back to vim with 'fg' , I feel it will be much better to get something like Eclipse IDE kind of stuff with terminal. Just one screen, where you have code above and output below.

Comment: You can have that with two terminal windows, no need to add tmux and its associated learning curve.